# youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one. Error with installed

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl, ffprobe

I have installed ffprobe as well as added it to path and got this test file code:

```
import youtube_dl
import ffmpeg

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': "P:/DscMusic/testfile.wav",
    'noplaylist': True,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'wav',
        'preferredquality': '192', }]
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])

print("Done")
```

I got the error like described in the title.
So can anybody help me with this?

(Btw; I am going to use this for a discord.py Bot)

Comment: The error pretty much speaks for itself, the script cannot write to the specified location.

Comment: Are you sure you want to call your file "P:/DscMusic"? Maybe you have a folder of the same name.

Comment: @Matthias, oh, thanks for that hint. Now another problem appears; "youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one." Sure, you can say, I have to download ffprobe but it doesn't work. I have downloaded it as well as added to path

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that. I never worked with `youtube_dl`. I checked the documentation for my first comment, so that's why I could identify that problem.

Comment: @FlexGames `ffprobe` writes nothing on disk, just infos and not conversions. You need `ffmpeg` for transcoding. Also, your setting 'preferredquality': '192' does not mean anything in `wav` format, because  it's  lossless and not lossy. Are you sure  that  `ffmpeg` is installed and in your path?  It works fine  from the command line?

Comment: Already fixed it